# Dynamic JSON Response parsing to GSON model - Dynamic Key with Dynamic Data type

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I have a JSON response structured as follows:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "Owner": {
            "owner_name": "name",
            "title": "Standup meeting",
            "description": "..."
            // Other fields
        },
        "Moderator": [
            {
                "owner_name": "name",
                "title": "Standup meeting",
                "description": "..."
                // Other fields
            }
            // Potentially more objects in the array
        ]
        // Potentially more dynamic keys with objects or arrays of objects
    }
}
```

In this JSON response, there are various dynamic keys such as "Owner" and "Moderator," and each of them contains either a JSON object or an array of JSON objects. I need to create a GSON data class to parse this dynamic JSON response.

I am currently stuck with the following data class and am unsure if it is correct:

```
data class MineMeetResponse(
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: HashMap<String, ...>
)
```

I'm not sure if the above data model is correct. Could you please assist me in creating a GSON model for this dynamic JSON response?

Additionally, I would greatly appreciate guidance on writing unit test cases for this data model. Your assistance in both creating the data model and suggesting unit testing strategies would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the define all the object type in the Data tag as below and make them nullable.

```
data class MineMeetResponse (
        val status: Boolean,
        val data: Data
        )
    
data class Data (
            val owner: Owner? = null,
            val moderator: List<Owner>? = null,
            // more types here...
        )
        
data class Owner (
            val ownerName: String,
            val title: String,
            val description: String,
            // Other fields as nullable...
            // val foo: T? = null 
        )
```